# Analyze page to see which resource is not transfered in https

Tags: html, security, ssl, https

I'm trying to use SSL for all the traffic of my website: https://alireza-noori.com. After a lot of struggle I managed to install certificate and make the HTTPS work. However, whenever I visit my homepage, the browser tells me that there are some insecure resources in the page. But it doesn't tell me which ones. I double-checked the source code and didn't find any HTTP link. I've even added some code to `.htaccess` file to force all connections in HTTPS.

How can I know which resource is causing the problem?

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this issue and work out where the fonts were coming from? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @ZeviSternlicht I remember I solved it but the problem was with a theme I was using. I changed some of its code and checked all the resources. I'm not sure but I think the last problem which was bugging me was with a CSS file which was importing a font or other resource.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I managed too, was a Magento change I had to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer tools (Web Inspector) in Chrome will show you in the console which files failed to load. A similar result can be achieved with  the developer tools in any of the major browsers.

Here's more info on Chrome Developer Tools:

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Here's what I'm getting from the console when visiting your website:

- The page at https://alireza-noori.com/ displayed insecure content
  from
  http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ptserifcaption/v4/7xkFOeTxxO1GMC1suOUYWWhBabBbEjGd1iRmpyoZukE.woff.
- The page at https://alireza-noori.com/ displayed insecure content from
  http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/k3k702ZOKiLJc3WVjuplzJ1r3JsPcQLi8jytr04NNhU.woff.
- The page at https://alireza-noori.com/ displayed insecure content from
  http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTZ1r3JsPcQLi8jytr04NNhU.woff.
- The page at https://alireza-noori.com/ displayed insecure content from
  http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/EInbV5DfGHOiMmvb1Xr-hp1r3JsPcQLi8jytr04NNhU.woff.
- The page at https://alireza-noori.com/ displayed insecure content from
  http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/K88pR3goAWT7BTt32Z01mz8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff.

Looks like wherever the fonts are coming from is accessed without
   `https`.